# Apache Camel: Log/Persist exchange info of every processor / component of a route automatically

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

When using **Apache Camel** I want to persist exchange information before every processor / component of a route automatically without using wiretap processor in the route where errorHandlers are also applied in the route. I tried using interceptStrategy, but [interceptors are not triggered when errorHandlers](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12250) are applied in the route. It also came to my understanding that using custom InterceptStrategy is not intended for end-users. Does someone know an alternative for this?

---

We are currently looking at implementing `EventNotifierSupport` mentioned by @RomanVottner. With the implementation below we noticed that the `ExchangeSentEvent` is sent duplicate for some processors/endpoints.
**Why are ExchangeSentEvent sent multiple times for the same processor action?**

`context.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(new RouteHistoryEventNotifier());`

```
public class RouteHistoryEventNotifier extends EventNotifierSupport {

  private int retryCounter = 0;
  private String lastID = "";

  @Override
  public void notify(EventObject eventObject) throws Exception {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("notify eventname:  " + eventObject.getClass().getName() );

      if (eventObject instanceof ExchangeRedeliveryEvent) {
         ExchangeRedeliveryEvent event = (ExchangeRedeliveryEvent) eventObject;
         Exchange exchange = event.getExchange();
         String id = getProcessorName(exchange);
         retryCounter =  event.getAttempt(); 
         log.info("notify eventname:  " + event.getClass().getName()  + " - retry: " + retryCounter );
      }
      if (eventObject instanceof ExchangeSentEvent) {
          ExchangeSentEvent event = (ExchangeSentEvent) eventObject;
          Exchange exchange = event.getExchange();
          String id = getProcessorName(exchange);

          if(retryCounter > 0) {
             id = String.format("%s (%s)", id, retryCounter ); 
          }

        // write Exhange with timeTaken and processorId to Database
         myRepo.saveStep(id , exchange,startTime,  event.getTimeTaken());
      }
  }

  private String getProcessorName(Exchange exchange) {
      List<MessageHistory> list = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY, List.class);
      MessageHistory msgHistory = list.get(list.size() - 1);
      String id = msgHistory.getNode().getId();
      if (!lastID.equalsIgnoreCase(id) ) {
          lastID  = id;
          retryCounter = 0;
      }
      return id; 
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
Line 4762: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.503 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.CamelContextStartingEvent
Line 4950: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.607 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteAddedEvent
Line 4978: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.617 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteAddedEvent
Line 4996: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.619 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteStartedEvent
Line 5002: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.619 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteStartedEvent
Line 5005: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.619 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.CamelContextStartedEvent
Line 5010: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.620 [d763f7b:1624c6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5011: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.620 [d763f7b:1624c6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeCreatedEvent
Line 5014: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.620 [d763f7b:513548] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5018: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.621 [d763f7b:61dde6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5020: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.622 [d763f7b:783f41] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5024: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.625 [d763f7b:61dde6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5026: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.626 [d763f7b:9d0511] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5030: 2018-06-26 14:58:44.626 [d763f7b:4be680] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5118: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.353 [d763f7b:acf181] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5123: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.353 [d763f7b:61dde6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5126: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.354 [d763f7b:ac8552] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSendingEvent
Line 5130: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.360 [d763f7b:61dde6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5133: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.360 [d763f7b:1624c6] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeCompletedEvent
Line 5136: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.360 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent
Line 5138: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.360 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.CamelContextStoppingEvent
Line 5183: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.364 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteStoppedEvent
Line 5185: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.364 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteRemovedEvent
Line 5262: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.365 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteStoppedEvent
Line 5286: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.366 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.RouteRemovedEvent
Line 5301: 2018-06-26 14:58:45.367 [d763f7b:d7637b] [ntExecutorGroup] INFO   fiers.RouteHistoryEventNotifier - notify eventname:  org.apache.camel.management.event.CamelContextStoppedEvent
```

You can also see [OpenTracingEventNotifier](https://github.com/neowal1/neowal1/blob/15e3e89283863c955d3ec0d78c3cd8c0d9dfecdc/components/camel-opentracing/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/opentracing/OpenTracingTracer.java) or [ZipkinEventNotifier](https://github.com/neowal1/neowal1/blob/15e3e89283863c955d3ec0d78c3cd8c0d9dfecdc/components/camel-zipkin/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/zipkin/ZipkinTracer.java) as example

Comment: Interesting to see that InterceptStrategy shouldn't be used by end-users when actually @ClausIbsen included it in [Camel in Action 2](https://www.amazon.com/Camel-Action-Claus-Ibsen/dp/1617292931/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1528980875&sr=8-1&keywords=Camel+in+Action+2) in chapter 8.6 and 16. You might have a look at `EventNotifierSupport`, though this mostly works for prior or after sending to an other route or returning before or after that which might force a route restructure.

Comment: @RomanVottner : I also thought this was interesting. 

Especially after that ClausIbsen himself replied that it shoud not be used. -> (http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12250)

Comment: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Bug-with-addEventNotifier-fires-two-exchange-sent-events-for-each-Exchange-sent-td5737086.html